# Do people use other limits than products, equalizers and pullbacks?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

This is a somewhat vague question. I've seen several introductions to category theory, and when someone presents (co)limits, the typical examples are always (co)products, (co)equalizers and pullbacks/pushouts. I know how these are important and pop up a lot in different contexts in many areas of mathematics. But the definition of (co)limits are very general, and I've never seen any other concrete diagrams being used. So I was wondering whether there are any other *useful* (co)limits that people use (of course, "useful" might very much depend on interpretation, but any examples would be interesting to me).

Comment: $p$-adic numbers as limit over $\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Perhaps [Inverse limit - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit)?

Comment: In the definition of Čech cohomology we take a colimit over all open covers of a topological space. Certainly a very complicated diagram. The stalk of a sheaf is another definition of where general collimits are used. Also if you want to compute these things called left Kan extensions you need cocompleteness of your category, i.e existence of *every* colimit over small diagrams.

Comment: The intersection of a decreasing sequence of subsets of a set is the limit of the sequence with respect to inclusion maps. For example, the Cantor set is the limit of the sequence of approximations obtained by gradually removing middle thirds. And dually, the union of an increasing sequence of subsets of a set is the colimit of the sequence with respect to inclusion maps.

Comment: Invert an element $x$ in a ring $R$ acting on a module $M$ by taking the colimit of $M \xrightarrow{x} M \xrightarrow{x} \cdots$. More generally, "sequential" limits and colimits occur frequently: taking the colimit of $A_1 \to A_2 \to A_3 \to ...$, for example, as in the comment by @AndreasBlass.

Comment: In one of the constructions of a Kan extension, we take the limits of diagrams of the form $(F\downarrow d)$ for a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: A useful fact is that every (algebraic thing) is the colimit of the diagram of all maps into it from finitely presentable (algebraic things.) This colimit can be rather arbitrary.

Comment: Right, a diagram in the shape of natural numbers with the arrows going in one or the other direction makes a lot of sense as another "concrete general example" — that's perhaps even the most intuitive connection of category theory limits to standard calculus limits. And then there are constructions where one does not take one concrete fixed diagram, but some (possibly quite wild) diagram coming from the construction itself. Thank you all for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly, filtered colimits (also called direct limits) and cofiltered limits (also called inverse limits) pop up a lot :

inverse limits come up for instance in the definition of the $p$-adics, or whenever you have something profinite (e.g. in infinite Galois theory);

and direct limits come up whenever you have "finite" things that are easier to understand and you want to decompose an object in terms of its "finite" subobjects. For instance any algebraic gadget (in the sense of a model of an algebraic theory) is a filtered colimit of its finitely generated subgadgets, which often allows one to reduce the study to finitely generated things.  Or you can also express infinite coproducts as filtered colimits of the finite coproducts, and those are sometimes easier to understand.

Here are some concrete examples:

-inverse limits : $\mathbb Z/p^n$, with maps $\mathbb Z/p^{n+1}\to \mathbb Z/p^n$ being the canonical projection, the inverse limit is $\mathbb Z_p$, the $p$-adics, more generally for a commutative ring $R$ and an ideal $I$, $\varprojlim_n R/I^n$ is the so-called $I$-adic completion of $R$; for a field $K$, $Gal(\overline K/K) = \varprojlim_LGal(L/K)$, where $L$ runs in the finite Galois subextensions of $\overline K/K$;

-filtered colimits: $\mathbb Z/p^n$, with the inclusion $\mathbb Z/p^n\to \mathbb Z/p^{n+1}$ being induced by multiplication by $p$ (very different from the inverse system), the colimit of that is $\mathbb Z/p^\infty$ (the $p$-primary part of $\mathbb{Q/Z}$); in topological spaces, $\mathbb RP^\infty = \mathrm{colim}_n \mathbb RP^n$ : the infinite projective space is the colimit of the finite dimensional projective spaces; in vector spaces $K[x] = \mathrm{colim}_n K[x]_{\leq n}$ (space of polynomials of degree $\leq n$)

Or in topology, compactness plays the role of finiteness, and you may be happy when you can decompose some space in the form of a filtered colimit of compact spaces (e.g. nice CW complexes)

Another type of colimit that often comes up in homotopy theory is colimits over $\Delta^{op}$, the simplex category.

Other examples have been mentioned in the comments : for the definition of the stalk of a sheaf at a point, or for a left Kan extension, you have various weird types of diagrams that can come up - and sometimes you don't know, or don't even want to know what that diagram looks like, that's why it's interesting to have a general theory of (co)limits, so you can make do without knowing the specific shape of the diagram.

Comment: I think with the comments and this answer there is enough examples to close this question, so I would accept this as answer, as it is the only one — but for anyone reading this in the future, who might not be familiar with (co)filtered (co)limits, it might be useful if there was the very concrete example of a sequence going in one or the other direction at the start of this answer, as an example of another very concrete widely used diagram? I think the rest of the answer would be intuitively much clearer and self-contained.

Comment: You're right, I'll add some examples !